# How can I get the full, symbolicated stack trace when a panic or error occurs in Rust code that's been called via FFI, for the iOS platform?

Tags: ios, rust, crash-reports

Since unwinding across an FFI boundary is unsafe, how can I record the:

- stack trace of the Rust code
- the C/Objective-C code that was calling into that Rust code
- the Rust code that was calling into that C/Objective-C code
- etc.?

How can we do it if unsafe code called within Rust causes an segfault or some other low-level crash?

I'm particularly interested in this for iOS, where getting crash reports from the wild is crucial. One thing that would help, it seems to me, is that maybe `backtrace(3)` would work from an `extern fn` in Rust to get the C/Objective-C piece directly above it?

Comment: I would say piece-meal, one stack boundary at a time, but I am not sure what libraries could be used for that to be honest.